# SSL's don't work on both www. and non www. when using SNI in IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2012, sni

I am trying to migrate some ASP websites from a Windows 2008 environment where each host using an SSL is on a seperate IP. I would like to move these websites to a Windows 2012 environment where each website uses SNI so that the server only needs one IP address. The websites work fine without the SSL, however when I add the SSL binding in the format https://website.com, https://www.website.com gives the error connection refused, and vice versa. Please can someone help me solve this problem, it's stopping me from migrating any of these websites using SSL's.

Thanks.

Comment: As this question is not about programming it is probably off topic for StackOverflow.  You may want to post this to http://serverfault.com/ instead.  However you are going to have to give a lot more details about what configuration settings you have.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try posting there. I have searched seemingly the entire web and cannot find a similar situation to this!